# xquery include xml file name

Tags: xquery, filenames, xmlspy

I have the following code snippet in XMLSPY which runs properly:

```
xquery version "1.0";
<query2>
{
for $r in /reviews/review
return $r/reviewer
}
</query2>
```

How do I include xml filename in xpath, something as abc.xml/reviews/review ??

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the question by myself:

```
<query2>
{
    for $r in doc("reviews.xml")/reviews/review
    return $r/reviewer
}
</query2>
```